# Unable to add data to Oracle Custom Record - Error - Subscript beyond count

Tags: oracle, user-defined-types

I have created Custom Oracle Record Type and I am trying to populate with some values and trying to access the same in another stored procedure (actually I will be calling from Java — I am getting the same error in Java too) but I am getting "Subscript beyond count" error message.

I am just a beginner to Stored Procedures.
Below is what I have done.

**Oracle Customer Record Type**

```
create or replace type learnerMapCustomRecord as object(activityName varchar2(20),activityDescn varchar2(20));

create or replace type learnerMapCustomRecordTable as table of learnerMapCustomRecord;
```

Stored Procedure to populate values to record type

```
create or replace PROCEDURE getLearnerMapDetails(learnerMapCustomRecord out learnerMapCustomRecordTable) as 
cursor c1 is select object_name,status from user_objects  where rownum <= 2;
c c1%rowtype;
i number:=1;
begin
  learnerMapCustomRecord := learnerMapCustomRecordTable();
  open c1;
  loop
    fetch c1 into c;
    EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line(c.object_name||'==>'||c.status);
  --  learnerMapCustomRecord.extend;
    learnerMapCustomRecord(I).activityName:=C.OBJECT_NAME;
    learnerMapCustomRecord(i).activityDescn:=c.status;
    i:=i+1;
  end loop; 
end;
```

Stored proc from where I am invoking the above SP to access the list of Custom Record Types.

```
create or replace procedure data_collection_extract as
learnerMapCustomRecord learnerMapCustomRecordTable;
begin
  getLearnerMapDetails(learnerMapCustomRecord);
  for i in learnerMapCustomRecord.first..learnerMapCustomRecord.last
  LOOP
   dbms_output.put_line(learnerMapCustomRecord(i).activityName||'==>'||learnerMapCustomRecord(i).activityDescn);
  end loop; 
end;

set serveroutput on;
exec data_collection_extract();
/
show error;
Error report -
ORA-06533: Subscript beyond count
ORA-06512: at "FOL_DEV.GETLEARNERMAPDETAILS", line 13
ORA-06512: at "FOL_DEV.DATA_COLLECTION_EXTRACT", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1
06533. 00000 -  "Subscript beyond count"
*Cause:    An in-limit subscript was greater than the count of a varray
           or too large for a nested table.
*Action:   Check the program logic and explicitly extend if necessary.
```

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your `CURSOR` returns [more than 2147483647 rows](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS00512) ? As it is the maximum a nested table can hold.

Answer (score 1):

Several issues:

1. You are not extending your collection (despite that the `.extend()` method is there ... commented out).
2. You are not instantiating your object class `learnerMapCustomRecord`.
3. You are not closing your cursor `c1`.
4. Your output parameter has the same name as your class, effectively making instantiation of your object class more difficult because of default identifier scope resolution.
5. You are making too many roundtrips to the SQL engine (and too much work for yourself as well) by using row-by-row `fetch` where you can do a regular cursor `for`-loop or a bulk fetch.

Solution:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE getLearnerMapDetails(theOutput out learnerMapCustomRecordTable)
as
  cursor c1 is select object_name,status from user_objects  where rownum <= 2;
  c c1%rowtype;
begin
  theOutput := learnerMapCustomRecordTable();
  open c1;
  loop
    fetch c1 into c;
    EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line(c.object_name||'==>'||c.status);
    theOutput.extend();
    theOutput(theOutput.last) := new learnerMapCustomRecord(
        activityName => c.object_name,
        activityDescn => c.status
    );
  end loop; 
  close c1;
end;
```

... and with the SQL engnie roundtrips reduction ...

```
create or replace PROCEDURE getLearnerMapDetails(theOutput out learnerMapCustomRecordTable)
as
  cursor c1 is select object_name,status from user_objects  where rownum <= 2;
begin
  theOutput := learnerMapCustomRecordTable();
  for c in c1 loop
    dbms_output.put_line(c.object_name||'==>'||c.status);
    theOutput.extend();
    theOutput(theOutput.last) := new learnerMapCustomRecord(
        activityName => c.object_name,
        activityDescn => c.status
    );
  end loop; 
end;
```

... and if you want to do it a "tough guy way", then you could do it this way ...

```
create or replace PROCEDURE getLearnerMapDetails(theOutput out learnerMapCustomRecordTable) as
begin
    select new learnerMapCustomRecord(
        activityName => object_name,
        activityDescn => status
    )
    bulk collect into theOutput
    from user_objects
    where rownum <= 2;
end;
```

Enjoy.